# logic - how to translate this into predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

"the result of additon between two negative integers are negative integers too"

i'm thinking of:
x,y,z as negative integers

∀x∀y∃z(x+y=z)

thanks in advance

Comment: What you wrote conveys that the sum $x+y$ always exists, but your problem concerns the property of being "negative integers".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe $$\forall x\forall y(x<0  \wedge y<0\to x+y<0) $$

Answer (score 1):

x,y are integers

$\forall x\forall y((x<0\land y<0)\to (x+y<0)) $